# Changing KDE's oxygen-gtk3 colors for tooltips (fixing Firefox 46)

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde

I use KDE (Kubuntu 14.04), the Oxygen theme and Firefox, and FF46 has several bugs with GTK3, the most annoying being displaying tooltips as dark text over a barely darker background.

So I'am looking for a temporary change in them settings to either have the text in white (but I think the problem is that FF46 isn't using the theme color) or having a lighter background.

As far as I can't tell the tooltip background is not even a solid color but a vertical gradient, from roughly 60,53,48 at the top to 42,37,33 at the bottom and I cannot relate these to some contents of the theme in /usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-3.0/ (kdeglobals, oxygenrc or the two CSS files).

So, where are these colors defined?

Comment: Try looking at `gtk.css`: I have a line with `@define-color tooltip_bg_color #333333;`. See if changing the hex value helps.

Comment: This line is not in my gtk.css, and adding it completely wrecks the display...

Comment: Same here. [Someone says](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?70057-Firefox-46-0-UI-issues&s=e8496dc7517e54f76ae0c216ee30b3c2&p=387078&viewfull=1#post387078) the problem fixed in FF47. Let's wait a bit for it appear in the repository, and see.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I hope so, because that's not the only problem with FF46 (it hoses the file selector, too....). But I tried the other themes and I don't like their looks. Btw, thx for introducing me to Kubuntu Forums, they look a bit more active than the KDE ones.

Comment: Well, just if anybody interested: although upgrading to FF47 didn't help, but upgrading distro 14.04 → 16.04, did help. I guess, there were some themes fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the colour in the System Settings, which will fix it for all applications, not just Firefox.

On Kubuntu 14.04 LTS:
System Settings > Application Appearance > Colours (side selection) > Colours (the tab) > Tooltip Background and Tooltip Text

Comment: Yes, that what I did three weeks ago :)

Comment: It does not fix it for me in Kubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, on Firefox 48...

Comment: This does not work anymore on Kubuntu 20.04.